# Java HttpClient synchronous vs asynchronous request

Tags: java, rest, httprequest, java-http-client

The Java `HttpClient` can send either a synchronous or an asynchronous request. The synchronous method blocks until a response has been received, while the asynchronous does not. But what does this mean for a developer? Generally speaking, I assume that asynchronous should be more efficient. Yet, the fact that synchronous requests exist, means that there are usages for them as well. So the question is:
When should I send a synchronous request and when should I send an asynchronous?
My assumption is there is no specific rule on this but there should be some well-known cases, when one is a particularly better option than the other.

 In my current case, I am trying to write an app for searching articles from a web API, which has paging. However, my question is not just about this particular case. I'd like to receive some general tips on how to chose one of the two approaches, as well.

Comment: Always use a synchronous call, unless you have a specific reason not to.  It’s simpler and easier to follow.  An asynchronous call might make sense when you want to make sure the current thread does not get held up due the speed of the network, such as when making a call from a Swing and JavaFX application.

Comment: @VGR All right. A synchronous call is indeed so much easier to implement. Especially since my task is to provide an API, not a GUI or Console app, I guess it would really be an overkill. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Async HTTP requests are good in case you need to make many requests in parallel, because you are saving on native thread overhead. This is especially true, if it takes a long time to receive the response from the server. (However, if you are using Virtual threads released in Java 21, this is becoming less relevant).
2. Async requests might be good if you need to make several HTTP requests in parallel, and return any first response that you get, while cancelling other requests.
3. You will have to make async requests, if you are writing code inside an async context already, for example, an asynchronous Spring controller method.